# Pass parameter to callback function inside a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

I am working in client-side JavaScript. I want to run a callback inside a forEach loop, and pass the value of the variable in the forEach loop to the callback.

Here is my (broken) code:

```
var tags = ['foo', 'bar'];
var displayTag = function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.warn("Error from server", error);
    }
    else {
        console.log(tag);
    }
};
tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    if (is_project) {
        Project.addTag(visualisation_id, tag, displayTag);
    } else {
        Page.addTag(page_id, tag, displayTag);
    }
});
```

When I run this I'm getting a warning that `tag` in `console.log(tag)` is undefined.

How can I pass the value of tag to the callback? I'm sure this is simple!

Comment: `displayTag` receives arguments named `error` and `results`, no `tag` included in the argument list. Arguments used in the function body are named (declared) in the argument list of the function definition, not when calling the function.

Comment: Sure - I understand that, as I hope the question makes clear! The question is about how I _can_ pass the value of `tag` to the function. Is there a way, or do I need to write the function twice inside `forEach`?

Comment: Just change change function addTag to pass the tag to the callback

Comment: @mplungjan How?

Comment: I don't know. one of the downvotes is due to such missing code

Comment: There's no call of `displayTag` in the provided code. Most likely the invocation is done in `Project.addTag` method. You should show that function too. Or `Page.addTag`, which ever calls `displayTag`, and causes the error.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, function `displayTag` is a callback function that is passed as a parameter to `Page.addTag` and `Project.addTag`. It seems that `Page.addTag` and/or `Project.addTag` will be calling that callback function. But it is not known if the OP is able/allowed to change that code.

Comment: @Richard `displayTag = function(error, result, tag)` - you can add a parameter this way. Assuming that's how the `.addTag` methods would pass it. We don't know what they do, so really the only thing we can advise is "add the parameter" - we don't know how you call this function.

Comment: @BartHofland Well, that is something we don't know before OP tells us.

Comment: @Teemu - ah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a callback in addTag

```
this.addTag(visualisation_id, tag, callback) {
  callback(error, result)
}
```

Change it to

```
this.addTag(visualisation_id, tag, callback) {
  callback(error, result, tag)
}
```

Comment: The `addTag` functions seem to be defined in the (external) classes/modules `Project` and `Page`. It is unknown if the OP can change those functions.

Comment: But I agree that your proposal makes perfect sense. If I would have created functionality regarding tags myself, and my addTag function in several classes like `Page` and `Project` would call a callback function that is passed to that addTag function, I would pass the affected tag as an argument to the callback function call too in case the callback function would need it.

Comment: Pfff. I hate callbacks. Only just for the complex explanations you need to write. ;)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing, since I can change those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a Higher-Order Function (a function that returns a function):

```
var tags = ['foo', 'bar'];
var createDisplayTagCallback = function(tag) {
  return function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error from server", error);
    }
    else {
      console.log(tag);
    }
  }
};
tags.forEach(function (tag) {
  if (is_project) {
    Project.addTag(visualisation_id, tag, createDisplayTagCallback(tag));
  } else {
    Page.addTag(page_id, tag, createDisplayTagCallback(tag));
  }
});  </script>
```

Haven't tested this code though...